# On mobile, fixed div blocks content when user double taps

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

The issue I'm having is that my when mobile users double tap to zoom in on content in my right container, the left container which I've set as fixed, jumps in front of the zoomed content.  I'm at a loss how to correct this.

**CSS**

```
#left_container{
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
}

#right_container{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 600px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 210px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="left_container">
    <div id="header"> 
        <center><h2>Hello World</h2></center>
    </div>

    <div id="globe"> 
        <img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/Kmitu/Kmitu0706/Kmitu070600073/1126687-globe-isolated-on-pure-white-background.jpg" width="200" height="200">
    </div>

    <div id="navigation_buttons">
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PROJECTS*</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG*</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>            
        </ul>
    </div>   
</div>

<div id="right_container">
    <h1>Content</h1>   
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's just normal behavior of `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you need to learn about positioning an element to `fixed`..

First off, any element that is set to `fixed` or `absolute` will need a value for [ `top` and`left` ] OR [ `bottom` and `right` ]. Note: `float:left;` won't affect a `fixed` element, you meant to use `left:0;`

Second, a `fixed` or `absolute` positioned element will overlay any `static` (default position) positioned element.

SO what's happening is, when the user zooms in, the window scope gets smaller, causing your `fixed` element to cross over more area of the screen.

What you need to do is, either make your design responsive using Javascript/jQuery, this way you can foresee the ocation of an user 'zooming' in.

The other way you can do this is by giving your `fixed` element a `right` of 0 and nesting it inside another element with and a position of `relative`... this will bind your `fixed` element and restrict it's bounds.

You might want to read up on the `position` property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp